# How to fix FAB inside activity?

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to add a BottomAppBar to my activity but there's a error : " java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mathmech.cards/com.mathmech.cards.activity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar"

I tried to follow guides on web but nothing helped

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
            app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="bottom" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

EDIT: added styles.xml

```xml
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

Comment: Have you added the correct dependency for `BottomAppBar`?

Comment: @SaurabhThorat 
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0-beta01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0-beta01'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'
}

Comment: Post your `styles.xml`

Comment: @SaurabhThorat here it is (edited post)

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-navigation-view/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using your parent theme as `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`, use `Theme.MaterialComponents` or its descendant.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this style in your Bottom App Bar XML.

```
style=”@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar”
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, changing `Theme.AppCompact.Light.DarkActionBar` to `Theme.MaterialComponents` will help your see the xml in layout editor.

Also, you can follow this article 
[Implementing BottomAppBar I: Material Components for Android](https://medium.com/material-design-in-action/implementing-bottomappbar-material-components-for-android-f490c4a01708)